# React Native, React Native Keychain. Questions

Tags: react-native, react-native-keychain

I have some questions regarding react native and react native keychain.
I'm new to react native and trying to build a mobile application.

1. How can I store cookies in react native and if it's possible how can I send it to backend just like in web where I have to do is ( credentials : "include" )? ( I found some people say it's possible and other said no it's not possible. So I'm confused. )
2. Which is the secure way to authenticate ? ( I have access token and refresh token )
3. Will the user have to login again after the mobile device is restarted cuz the saved token is lost ?
4. How to make the application responsive since there is no media query. ( or might be. So far I haven't seen media query )
5. Which is the best animation library navigation library in your opinion ?

Qestions I forgot to add.

1. Is react native keychains encrypted ?
2. Can I store my refresh token or access token in react native keychains ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1,2,6,7 i guess this should answer how to safely store data.

[Secure storage in react native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/security#secure-storage)

So basically on ios its keychain as you mentioned and in android its secured shared preferences.

3. No, if you store data in the above methods, it persists even if the user has closed / logged out. If only the user has uninstalled it gets removed.
4. You can use flex property to make it responsive , and calculate the width and height dynamically . `const width = Dimensions.get("window").width`

5.Best animation library is react-native-reanimated. it works pretty smooth since everything runs on native thread. [reanimated](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated)

Do reach me out in case of any concerns.